# Loose skin after making chicken curry in pressure cooker

Tags: chicken, curry

I'm trying to make chicken (skin on) curry in the pressure cooker (only in pressure cooker btw), and at the, the thigh pieces to a bit of loose skin over it which doesn't feel right.

How could I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Curries are moist, and you will never get crisp skin when it's cooked in a moist environment. Even if you cook the chicken separately in an oven and crisp up then skin before adding the curry sauce afterwards the skin will quickly get soggy.

There's no way around this, you can't have a moist curry and crispy skin. To avoid soggy skin in your curry peel remove the skin first and cook the chicken without. I like to fry off a couple of the skins in a bit of oil until they are browned, then remove them before starting to cook the rest as it gives a bit of fried chicken flavor to the dish, if the skins are very crispy you can put a bit of salt on and eat them separately.

Answer (score 0):

Well, pressure cookers are fantastic for making tender, flavorful meat fast, but they don't provide the dry, high heat necessary to render fat and crisp up skin. Here are a few methods you could try:

Before you place the chicken in the pressure cooker, you can sear the skin in a hot pan (you can use a bit of oil, salt, and pepper). This will help to render some of the fat and tighten the skin. After you've browned the skin, you can then proceed to cook the chicken in the pressure cooker as per your recipe.

Or.. After pressure cooking, place the chicken thighs on a baking sheet and put them under the broiler in your oven. Monitor them closely to make sure the skin doesn't burn. This should help to tighten and crisp up the skin.